# Skeleton Loading in Ext JS grid

Tags: extjs, skeleton-ui

What is the easiest way to apply skeleton loading(as shown in the image below) in the Ext JS grid and similar components?
[Skeleton Loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb4UN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For grids i would start by looking at the "emptyText" config.A text to be shown when no rows are loaded. This can also include HTML tags. Try to build something there.

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/classic/Ext.panel.Table.html#cfg-emptyText